# How to create object given user is login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

i have a user who's login, and i wanna create an object of another model (generator) . Each **user has_many generators.**
****Rake routes****

[image]
**User model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :generators
  has_many :results, :through=>:generators
```

**Generator model**

```
class Generator < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :result , :dependent => :destroy
  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessible :choice, :primer_length, :random_primer_generated, :generator_id
```

**Result model**

```
class Result < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :generator_id,:ncbi_ref_seq,:genome_seq, :genome_sample
   belongs_to :generator
   belongs_to :user, :through=>:generators
```

in the **Generator controller**:

```
    def new
        @generator=Generator.new(:user_id=> current_user.id)
    end

 def create    
    @generator = current_user.generators.build(params[:generator])
    @generator.choice = params[:choice]
      if params[:choice] == 'Randomly'
          @generator.random_generate(generator_params)
      elsif params[:choice] == 'Specified ATGC'
          @generator.specified_ATGC(params[:no_A],params[:no_T],params[:no_G],params[:no_C])
      elsif params[:choice] == 'Seating'
          @generator.seating(params[:user_seq])
      end

    @generator.result_choice=params[:result_choice]
    @generator.save
    respond_to do |format|
       if @generator.result_choice == 'Yes'
              format.html { redirect_to(generator_path(@generator)) }
       else
              format.html { redirect_to(user_generator_path(current_user.generators) ) }
       end
     end 

  end
```

Whenever is click the submit_tag button in the form, i get this error `No route matches [POST] "/users/2/generators/new"` and the URL is `http://localhost:3000/users/2/generators/new`. It is suppose to go to the generator index and show what this user has create(generator). How do i fix this error ?

**FORM**

```
<%= form_for (current_user) do %>
        <% if current_user.errors.any? %>
            <div id="error_explanation">
              <h2><%= pluralize(current_user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this generator from being saved:</h2>

              <ul>
              <% current_user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                <li><%= msg %></li>
              <% end %>
              </ul>
            </div>
        <% else %>
        <fieldset class ="primer">
        <legend><strong>Method Use :</strong></legend><br>  
            <h3 align="left"><font size ="5"><b>Step 1: <u>Choose only ONE of the methods</u></font></b></h3> 
        <table class="p_gen">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th class="method1"><label>Randomly</label><br />
                <%= radio_button_tag(:choice, 'Randomly', true )%>
                <p> ( Generate a primer randomly )</p></th>

                <th class="method2"><label>Specified ATGC</label><br />
                <%= radio_button_tag(:choice,'Specified ATGC')%> 
                <p> ( Generate a primer with number of A,T,G and C )</p></th>

                <th class="method3"><label>Seating</label><br />
                <%= radio_button_tag(:choice,'Seating')%> 
                <p> ( Generate a primer according to your preference )</p></th>
             </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <tr>
                <td class="method1">
                    <p> Input length of the primer you want : </p>
                    <label>Primer Length :</label>
                    <%= number_field_tag :primer_length , min: 6 , max: 35%>
                </td>
                <td class="method2">
                    <p>Input the number of each base the primer should have</p>
                    <label>Number of A :</label>
                    <%= number_field_tag :no_A %><br />
                    <label>Number of T :</label>
                    <%= number_field_tag :no_T %><br />
                    <label>Number of G :</label>
                    <%= number_field_tag :no_G %><br />
                    <label>Number of C :</label>
                    <%= number_field_tag :no_C %><br />
                    Total bases:<span></span>
                </td>   
                <td class="method3">
                    <p> Input your preference sequence (only IUPAC nucleotide).</p>
                    <p><b><u>IUPAC Nucleotide :</u></b></p>
                    <p>A,T,G,C,R,Y,S,W,K,M,B,D,H,V,N </p>
                    Example: <br /> 
                    Preference primer = TAGGCT<b>N</b>TTA<b>N</b>GAC<b>N</b> <br />
                    N = Any base ( A/ T / G / C) <br /><br />               
                    <label>Desired sequence :</label><br>
                    <%= text_field_tag :user_seq ,nil, maxlength: 35%>
                </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </fieldset>
        <br>

        <fieldset class ="sample">
        <h4><font size="5"><b>Step 2: <u>Choose 'Yes' if you want to input reference sequence for Binding-time analysis </font></u></b></h4> 
        <legend><strong>Do you have NCBI data to extract / FASTA file to input?</strong></legend><br>
            <label>Yes</label>
            <%= radio_button_tag(:result_choice,'Yes')%> 
            <label>No</label>
            <%= radio_button_tag(:result_choice,'No')%>
        <br>
        </fieldset>

        <br><div class = "button"> 
           <%=submit_tag("Generate", :class => "Gbutton_class") %>
        </div>  
    <%end %>    
<%end%>
```

Comment: i've updated my form. In this form, if i put current_user, i get error uninitialized constant UsersController when i click submit. It's suppose to return http://localhost:3000/users/2/generators .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problems.

1) you should build form for new object - in your case it is `@generator`.

```
<%= form_for(@generator, :url => user_generators_path(current_user)) do |f| %>
```

2) you need build form inputs based on variable `f`

```
# something like this (you can find some examples in docs or google)
<%= f.radio_button(:choice,'Specified ATGC')%> 
<%= f.radio_button(:choice,'Seating')%>

<%= f.number_field :no_A %><br />
```

3) errors will have `@generator` - not `current_user`

```
<% @generator.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
```

4) you have space between form and `(` - it can be a problem for parser

```
# it is wrong
<%= form_for (some_params) do %>
# it is correct
<%= form_for(some_params) do %>
```

PS I see these problems in your form but I think there are some other issues as well

Comment: well before this, i haven't include user with the generator. But now i need a user to link with generators. so they're all messed up. I'll try your solutions n c

Comment: Gotva, how should i code my generator index now ? I wan to show only own user's record. Now it's  <% @generators.each do |generator| %> . I get an error Unknown key: through for        <% if generator.result.present?%>

Comment: result is another model. generator has_one result. So therefore the flow would be user has_many generators and generator has_one result

Comment: you should get generators from `current_user`. You can do it in controller `@generators = current_user.generators` or just in the view `<% current_user.generators.each do |generator| %>`. And if you use values from another model `Result` you should use includes (to avoid N+1 requests) `<% current_user.generators.includes(:result).each do |generator| %>`

Comment: i've included @generators = current_user.generators in my generator index controller. and <% current_user.generators.includes(:result).each do |generator| %> in the index view. I got an error Unknown key: through . Is this because i declared has_many :generators
  has_many :results, :through=>:generators in user model ?

Comment: try to get result without `includes`  and after it you will play with optimisation

Comment: i still get unknown key: through

Comment: I think you should post all your models: User, Generator, Result

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42744/discussion-between-bc2-and-gotva)

Comment: `belongs_to :user, :through=>:generators` remove this line. you don't have `user_id` column in table Result

Comment: Erm right now the index view is giving me error. No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"generators", :user_id=>"3"} missing required keys: [:id]

Comment: when there's not result needed, user click no and the index view will return <td id="change"><%= link_to 'Analyze',user_generator_path%></td>
           <td id="change"><%= link_to 'Delete', generator, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>

Answer (score 0):

You are posting to `http://localhost:3000/users/2/generators/new`, you should be POSTing to `http://localhost:3000/users/2/generators`.

Change your form's action to `user_generators_path(current_user)`

Comment: hi i've changed to current_user but i got an error uninitialized constant UsersController

Comment: your `form_for` shouldn't be to `current_user` but to `user_generators_path(current_user)`

Comment: if i change user_generators_path(current_user), i get : No route matches [POST] "/users/2/generators/new"